# Bootstrap 3 split dropdown button creation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a split dropdown button for my Django website and I'm using Bootstrap 3. Following is my code for the same:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li>
    <div class="btn-group">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Action</button>
     <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn dropdown-toggle"
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="caret"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
     </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

But I'm getting this kind of weird output.

[image]

I'm stuck at this problem from an hour. What am I doing wrong here? Why does the split arrow is not showing properly?

Comment: which bootstrap version you use

Comment: bootstrap 3.3.6

Comment: I check your code and It's working fine. may be you make mistake on rest of the code

Comment: Thanks!! I'll check it once again.

Answer (score 0):

I think your other CSS conflict, I have added demo check now

Your code is true

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Action</button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn dropdown-toggle"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/5yoe2uz1/2/